# Cloud services for machine learning for students

Tags: machine-learning, cloud

Are there any machine learning services free for students during their studies? What kind of services are there? I know only AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Also Azure has a program for students, however I am not sure whether they include Machine Learning services, check [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/community/education/)

Also, I think they give you [$200 as credit](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/?v=17.39a) once you register for a new account.

As for Google Cloud, they are offering [$300 for free accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial?_ga=2.75749077.-1957082670.1495156173&pli=1&page=0) and ability to access `all products`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Azure ML Studio, the services are limited in free version but that's totally okay for students.

Azure ML Studio is drag n drop workbench which is very cool but it also allows you to add your R or python code in the pipeline. So unless you are dealing with large dataset or deep learning stuff, Azure ML is one better place for you.